# Find the most recent record based on a specific value from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MyTable with this values (columns Id and MyDate)

```
10      2019-01-01
10      2018-01-01
25      2020-01-01
25      2005-01-01
```

I'd like keep record based on the most recent date, the result should be

```
10      2019-01-01
25      2020-01-01
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
Create table MyTable (Id int, DtDate Date)
insert into MyTable Values
(10, '2019-01-01'),
(10, '2018-01-01'),
(25, '2020-01-01'),
(25, '2005-01-01')

select * from (
select id
    , dtDate
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Id ORDER BY DtDate DESC) AS RowNo
from MyTable
)a where RowNo = 1
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8b3da658b2a8b3a0b11e4993bc8f8d3) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.* from (
select *,row_number() over (partition by ID order by date desc) as RN from Table ) t
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, max(myDate)
from myTable
group by id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select Id , MyDate
    from (select m.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by Id order by MyDate desc) as rowNum
          from MyTable m
         ) t
    where rowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Often, the faster method (with the right indexing) is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.mydate = (select max(t2.mydate) as t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

The best index is on `(id, mydate)`.

Note:  For a small amount of data, the approach doesn't make much difference.